# How was this python code analyze these classes with class diagram

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes, inheritance

Anyone please review my code and give some improvement suggestions.

I wrote code but not to the best standards. I think this site give some valuable suggestions

this code is for extracting xlsx or csv files int list of dicts and change the values of the dict objects after that concert that to json file

> excelparser.py

```
import pandas as pd

class ExcelParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = []       

    def extract(self, fileName):
        try:
            raw_excel=pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name=-1,
                                    na_values= None,keep_default_na=False)
            return [x for k, v in raw_excel.items() 
                    for x in v[v.columns.intersection(self.config)].to_dict(orient='records')]
        except:
            raw_excel=pd.read_csv(fileName,na_values= None,keep_default_na=False)
            return raw_excel[self.config].to_dict(orient='records')
```

> fc.py

```
from excel_parser import ExcelParser
from bank_writer_base import BankDataWriterBase
import json

class FreechargeImp(BankDataWriterBase):
    def __init__(self, input_path, output_path):
        self.bankObj = BankDataWriterBase(output_path)
        self.input_path = input_path

    def extract_json(self):
        conf = ["BNPL Activated", "Mobile Number"]
        obj = ExcelParser()
        obj.config = conf
        new_list = obj.extract(self.input_path)
        final_list = []
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            val = {}
            if new_list[i]["BNPL Activated"] == "No":
                val = {"App_id": "", "mobile_No": new_list[i]["Mobile Number"],
                       "loan_type": 33, "bank_id": 114, "latest_status": "Rejected", "bank_appid": "", "pan_no": "", "cust_downloadedapp": {"date": ""}, "cust_completedapp": {"date": ""}, "rejected": {"date": "", "rejection_reason": ""}, "sanctioned": {"amount": "", "date": "", "tenure": "", "interest_rate": ""}, "offer_accepted": {"date": ""}, "disbursed": {"amount": "", "los_id": "", "date": ""}}
            if new_list[i]["BNPL Activated"] == "Yes":
                val = {"App_id": "", "mobile_No": new_list[i]["Mobile Number"],
                       "loan_type": 33, "bank_id": 114, "latest_status": "disbursed", "bank_appid": "", "pan_no": "", "cust_downloadedapp": {"date": ""}, "cust_completedapp": {"date": ""}, "rejected": {"date": "", "rejection_reason": ""}, "sanctioned": {"amount": "", "date": "", "tenure": "", "interest_rate": ""}, "offer_accepted": {"date": ""}, "disbursed": {"amount": "", "los_id": "", "date": ""}}
            final_list.append(val)

        self.bankObj.write_file(json.dumps(final_list, indent=4))
```

> bankwriterbase.py

```
import json

class BankDataWriterBase:
    def __init__(self, input_path, output_path):
        self.input_path = input_path
        self.output_path = output_path
        

    def write_file(self, data, file):
        with open(self.output_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

> main.py

```
from fc import FreechargeImp
from bank_writer_base import BankDataWriterBase

input_path = input("Enter Input path = ")
output_path = input("Enter output path = ")

obj = FreechargeImp(input_path, output_path)
obj.extract_json()
```

I have also attached the class diagram here

> ```
> Class Diagram
> ```

[image]

Comment: The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code, not your concerns about it. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Hello at Code Review@SE. There online machine translators, improved compared to the past millennium. I find myself using one to translate text I'm about to post back to my first language to check if I expressed what I intend to. (Check the title, `files int list of dicts`, `concert that`. Try reversing the direction of translation. Take results with a grain of salt.)